# Python "all" execution

Tags: python

I'm confused about python's handing of objects during execution of [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all).  The documentation says that it is equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

From this trivial example, it seems like that is not the case:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, v):
    self.v = v

a = Foo(5)
b = None

if a and b and a.v == b.v:
  print("hello1")
else:
  print("goodbye1")

if all([a, b, a.v == b.v]):
  print("hello2")
else:
  print("goodbye2")
```

This causes the `all` line to crash with the error:

> goodbye1
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'v'
>   Line 13 in  (Solution.py)

I looks like [the cpython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L343-L344) *should* prevent this failure, but it doesn't. What's going on here?  Why does the same expression crash within `all`, but works as expected when expanded?

Comment: I thought this was a well researched question; can someone explain why this might have been downvoted?  I'd like to improve my questions going forward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: @AMC: No, it does not.  I have rephrased the question so that it's clear that is issue is around the order of evaluation of expressions.

Comment: Please don't change the question like you just did: it is now a completely different one, which makes all related answers more or less irrelevant. You should revert it to its original version and ask the edited version as a new, different question.

Answer (score 3):

Your list `[a, b, a.v == b.v]` has to be created before it can be passed to `all`, and all of its items have to be created before that, so `a.v == b.v` will have to be evaluated, and will fail as `b` is `None`.

On the other hand, `if a and b and a.v == b.v:` doesn't need to try and evaluate `a.v == b.v`, as Python knows that the whole expression will be False once it encounters `b`, which is falsy.

There is nothing wrong with the equivalent given in the documentation: `iterable` would have to be created first, but your list just can't be created.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is happening because **before** you call `all` you attempt to construct a list containing `a.v == b.v`

Answer (score 0):

It's because of lazy evaluation of boolean expression. It stops on 'and b' because b is None and not even try to get b.v.

Comment: Lazy evaluation isn't happening here, that is short-circuiting which `all` does as well, but the list is already created before `all` is involved

Answer (score 0):

The first `if` statement uses short-circuiting and stops when it hits `b`.  Since `b = None` this line evaluates to `False` and further evaluations are stopped early.

```
if a and b and a.v == b.v:
          ^--- Evaluation stops here.
```

This is why you don't see an error for that line, even you though you have `b.v` which normally would trigger an attribute error.

Using `all` evaluates all of the elements.  Since `b` is `None`, you will see the attribute error.

```
if all([a, b, a.v == b.v]):
                       ^---AttributeError here, None does not have a .b attr
```

Comment: It's not lazy evaluation, it's "short circuiting"

Comment: If it was truly lazy like this:
`def generator():
  yield a
  yield b
  yield a.v == b.v
all(generator())`
it did work as I imagined.